# Show complete text value using numberpicker for strings in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-number-picker

I am using numberpicker widget for showing a spinner wheel for string values. I want to show the complete text value in an item window in numberpicker. how can i achieve it? I have multiple number picker widgets aligned horizontally. I can view some of the text of an item but not all of it. Please help!

Comment: You can't show a string with a numberpicker, as the name itself states. On the other hand, you can use a RelativeLayout, and overlap a textview so that a string writes where you want. The string can be written from inside a listener.

Comment: Use a Spinner, instead. You can display texts (i.e.: "One", "Two", ...,  "FourtyFour") and retrieve the selected item position (i.e.: 0, 1, ..., 43).

Comment: @Beppi's i have used number picker for string array and it is working fine. the only problem is in the number picker wheel it is showing some of the text of an ktem and not the complete value. i am searching for some workaround like changing the text size of an item to show the complete value but didnt get any

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the NumberPicker with an array of string

xml:

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/np_string"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

code:

```
NumberPicker myNumberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np_string);

//Initializing a new string array with elements
final String[] values= {"one","two", "three", "four", "five"};

//Set min, max, wheel and populate.
myNumberPicker.setMinValue(0); 
myNumberPicker.setMaxValue(values.length-1);
myNumberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
myNumberPicker.setDisplayedValues(values);
```

Comment: i have done exactly the same thing. i want to display complete string value in a number picker item. i have multiple numberpicker widgets aligned horizontally. what should i do?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP is already using a NumberPicker in the way described by this answer and wants to know how to correct the horizontal truncation of long strings.

Answer (score 0):

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="numberPicker">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
</string-array>
```

fill NumberPicker

```
binding.numberPicker.setMaxValue(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numberPicker).length);
binding.numberPicker.setMinValue(0);        
binding.numberPicker.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numberPicker);
binding.numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
```

Comment: And for what do you call getResources? This numberpicker will have the entries 0 to 5 and the array will not be used,,,